# I can't choose my other radio button ive created?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create an Android app that converts temperature. My app works mostly but I can't select the other `RadioButton`. My app closes. I think it's when I have one clicked I need to set the other `RadioButton` to false. I have no clue what to do.

```
package com.example.temperatureconverter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.*;

public class Calculate extends Activity 
{
private EditText in, out;
//******************onCreate()*****************************
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle b) 
{
    super.onCreate(b);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculate);

    in = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
    out =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.results);

    in.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener()
    {   

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            double num, calc;
            if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))
            {
                if(v.getId() == R.id.radio1)
                {
                    num = Double.parseDouble(in.getText().toString());
                    calc = ((9.0/5.0) * num + 32);
                    out.setText(String.valueOf(calc));
                }
                else
                {
                    num = Double.parseDouble(in.getText().toString());
                    calc = (num - 32) * (9.0/5.0);
                    out.setText(String.valueOf(calc));
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
//******************buttonClick()*****************************  
public void buttonClick(View v)
{
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton)v).isChecked();
    switch(v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.radio1:
            if(checked)
            {

            }

            break;
        case R.id.radio2: 
            if(checked)
            {

            }
            break;
    }
}
}
```

here is my layout xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 >
<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/celsius"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"
        android:checked="true"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/farenheit"
        android:onClick="buttonClicked"/>   
 </RadioGroup>

 <EditText android:id="@+id/input"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="number"/>
 <EditText android:id="@+id/results"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:inputType="number"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my logcat

```
09-17 18:23:06.565: D/gralloc_goldfish(2225): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
09-17 18:23:11.775: D/AndroidRuntime(2225): Shutting down VM
09-17 18:23:11.775: W/dalvikvm(2225): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb3abcba8)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): Process: com.example.temperatureconverter, PID: 2225
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method buttonClicked(View) in the activity class com.example.temperatureconverter.Calculate for onClick handler on view class android.widget.RadioButton with id 'radio2'
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3810)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: buttonClicked [class android.view.View]
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:472)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:857)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3803)
09-17 18:23:11.855: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     ... 12 more
09-17 18:23:14.565: I/Process(2225): Sending signal. PID: 2225 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the crash. And why aren't you using `onCheckedChage()` instead of `onClick()`?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a buttonClicked method.  You have buttonClick only from what you posted.

Comment: I created the buttonClicked(View v) method that handles all my radio buttons. Do i need to call it in one of the methods above?

Comment: No, you don't. Compare the method spelling in Java and xml

Comment: Ok that fixed the problem being able to click either radio button. Now how do i create an if/else statement to direct which method to use?

Answer (score 0):

in your form xml, do you have something like this?

```
<RadioGroup>
  <RadioButton   android:onClick="buttonClick">
  <RadioButton   android:onClick="buttonClick">
</RadioGroup>
```

If so, android will automatically do the mutual-exclusion of the buttons.

Forced closure usually leads to a message in logcat. Are you connected as a debugger? Or can you see the logcat in your IDE?

To avoid exceptions, I'd surround your `parseDouble` call in a `try`:

```
try{
  num=Double.parseDouble(in.getText().toString());
  calc ....
  out.setText ...
} catch (NumberFormatException) { // what to do if there's no number?
  out.setText("enter a number");
}
```

Comment: yes i have android:onClick="buttonClick" in my code. i'll post my logcat now